# PDO::exec() blocking further query from working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm trying to implement pagination using PHP. I found that calling exec to the connected database prevents the further query calls from working.
The piece of code at hand:

```
<?php
    // Pagination logic
    //Here we count the number of results
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM gig";
    $total_pages = $db->exec($query);
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];
?>
```

After it if I try to use a query such as:

```
<?php>
foreach ($db->query("SELECT sname, start, venue FROM gig WHERE start = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'") as $a) {
  $row="<tr><td>$a[sname]</td><td>To be announced</td><td>$a[venue]</td></tr>\n";
  print $row;
}
?>
```

it returns

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

As soon as the first code block is removed, the query works fine. When I check the value of $total_pages, it's 0, so something must be going wrong along the way. As far as I know, I use it in the same way as the query(which works on its own), so is there any reason why it doesn't work?

The PDO is initialized in the following way:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_server", $db_user, $db_pw);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

session_start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a function of the STATEMENT object had after using querying to count the rows instead of exec:

```
$dbq = $db->query("SELECT * FROM gig");
$rows = $dbq->rowCount();
```

About the latter code block not working because of the exec failing - it seems to just be the way php queries work, if one fails, all fail. The foreach() error is for the object it's provided is not an array, for it failed.

Answer (score 0):

From [**Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

> PDO::exec() does not return results from a SELECT statement. For a
>   SELECT statement that you only need to issue once during your program,
>   consider issuing PDO::query(). For a statement that you need to issue
>   multiple times, prepare a PDOStatement object with PDO::prepare() and
>   issue the statement with PDOStatement::execute().

Comment: I had read that, but assumed I can use for I don't need any return results from the select statement. Replaced it with a a call to the query STATEMENT object instead to make it work.